# water boils in reserve tank

Tags: coolant, dodge, caliber

i use a dodge caliber and I have noticed the water boils in the reserve tank when the engine is hot and also when I park it overnight ,I have to refill the reserve tank the next morning because it is empty. what can be causing this problem ??

Comment: What year/engine is your Caliber? Have you checked the radiator cap? What you describe can be caused by a bad radiator cap.

Answer (score 1):

A strong possibility is that you have a small leak in the head gasket allowing combustion gas into the coolant system.  These usually leak both ways and so you may see excessive steam out the exhaust especially when first started.

You could also be simply overheating, but you don't mention any overheat light etc.